# Why does my CloudFormation template keep failing build for a simple DynamoDB with a single partition key?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a simple DynamoDB table using CloudFormation.

The creation of the Stack itself (not even reaching the creation of the table) keeps failing with an `Internal Failure. Rollback requested by user` message.

There is no additional information in the events tab. What is strange is that it fails on the Stack creation and not does not even try to create the DynamoDB resource.

This is for a simple DynamoDB table with a partition key and no sort key:

```
Resources:
  PortalRolesTable:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
    Properties:
     TableName: test-env-wb-portal-roles
        AttributeDefinitions:
         - AttributeName: name
           AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
            - AttributeName: name
              KeyType: HASH
```

This should create the table. I have another more complex template that builds successfully and creates a stack with secondary indexes and sort keys and TTL etc. I do not know why I am not getting any luck with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just used the wonderful [Console Recorder for AWS - Chrome Web Store](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/console-recorder-for-aws/ganlhgooidfbijjidcpkeaohjnkeicba?hl=en) to generate a template and got:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
    dynamodb1a42db5:
        Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
        Properties:
            TableName: "test-env-wb-portal-roles"
            BillingMode: "PROVISIONED"
            KeySchema: 
              - 
                AttributeName: "name"
                KeyType: "HASH"
            ProvisionedThroughput: 
                ReadCapacityUnits: 5
                WriteCapacityUnits: 5
            SSESpecification: 
                Enabled: false
```

It seems that `KeySchema` is a list of dictionaries, which needs the dash separate to the dictionary values.

Refer to the YAML code examples on: [AWS::DynamoDB::Table - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. the dictionary dashes were the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think the real problem was the missing **ProvisionedThroughput** property.

AWS doc says that [ProvisionedThroughput](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-dynamodb-table.html#cfn-dynamodb-table-provisionedthroughput) is required if you set BillingMode as PROVISIONED (that is also the default value for BillingMode)

When you've used *Console Recorder for AWS - Chrome Web Store* the addon also generated the ProvisionedThroughput property.

So, this code is right:

```
AttributeDefinitions:
- AttributeName: name
  AttributeType: S
```

but if you really want to solve the problem, the right answer is to add the ProvisionedThroughput property or change the BillingMode